# error while compiling java program

Tags: javac

I am compiling my java program,but i got stuck at one point. 
whenever i am seeting classpath from command window i am getting an error

```
D:\Project\D1>set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;
D:\Project\D1>javac hello.java
hello.java:3 error:cannot find symbol
public static void main(string arg[])
          symbol:class string
          location:class hello
hello.java:5: error:package system does not exist
system.out.println("hello");
2 errors
```

I am not getting what type of error is this.
Please help me to resolve this error

Comment: show your hello.java file

Answer (score 0):

`string` is not a class in Java. However, `String` is the correct class. Java is case-sensitive!

Your main method should look like:

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

Also, `System` is the correct class:

```
System.out.println("hello");
```

Entire method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
   System.out.println("hello");
}
```

Comment: And it must be System.out.println("hello");

Comment: That's not the entire program -- you left out the enclosing class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a clarity on Java standards,

In Java all the class names starts with Caps letter and followed by camel casing.
So in your case you are trying to access two classes,

String and System - These should be used with caps cases.

so

```
public static void main(String args[])
```

and

```
System.out.println("hello");
```

should resolve the issue.

It will be great if you change your class name as Hello.
That is a good start in Java and welcome to Java community.